# After I add a spesific sound file to res/raw I get error (java - android), Why is that?

Tags: java, android, audio

After I add the sound file "do.mp3" to res/raw I get this error:

> res\raw\do.mp3:0: error: invalid
>   symbol: 'do'

And their isn't reference to it in the R class. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way android generates the R.... values basically makes it so that java reserved keywords cannot be used as file names.

If you look in gen.[project.path].R.java you will see a static int for each resource.  The names have to be valid java names since it is a java file.